# What is wrong with my 'proof' of $i=1$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers, arithmetic, fake-proofs

So I recently learnt about $i$ and I can't wrap my head around the concept of $i^2=-1$ or that $\sqrt{-1}$ can even exist. Today I was thinking about $i$ again and thought of a "proof" that $i=1$.
$$i^4=1 \text{ and } 1^4=1 \text{ so } i^4=1^4$$
$$i^4=1^4 \to \sqrt[4]{i^4}=\sqrt[4]{1^4} \to i=1$$
But if $i=1$, then $i^2 \neq -1$. So I think I must have messed up something in the proof. Can someone point out where this went wrong? I know you can [$\text{"prove" }1=2$](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hI9CaQD7P6I) by accidentally dividing by $0$ and I suspect something similar is happening.

For anyone else having trouble with complex numbers @mrsamy commented this link and I found it quite helpful: https://www.math.toronto.edu/mathnet/answers/imaginary.html

Comment: In your first sentence, did you intend to write, "I can't wrap my head around the concept of $i^2=−1$ " ?

Comment: This argument was shown million times. You cannot blindly apply the rules of real numbers to the complex. The flaw is $i^4=1\implies i=\sqrt[4]1$. Anyway, $1=\sqrt[4]1$ is still true.

Comment: "can even exist."  Well, *nothing* in mathematics actually "exists".

Comment: https://www.math.toronto.edu/mathnet/answers/imaginary.html

Comment: Your error is that $\sqrt[k]{m^k} = \sqrt[k]{n^k}$ does *not* mean that $m =n$.  After all $(-2)^4 = 16$ and $2^4 = 16$ but $-2 \ne 2$.  If mapping $x \to f(x)$ is *not* one to one and thenn $f(m) = f(n)$ does *not* mean $m =n$.  ANd mapping $x\to x^k$ is *not* one to one.  For any $m$ there are (if we allow complex numbers) $k$ *DIFFERENT* $x$ so that $x^k = m$.  $i^4 = 1$ and $1^4 =1$ and $(-1)^4 = 1$ and $(-1)^4 = 1$ are the four different values.  That in *no* way means that $i=-i=1=-1$.

Comment: @fleablood yeah I guess numbers can't "exist" but what I mean is you can't have $i apples$ but you can have $5 apples$ or $.5 apples$ or "owe" apples $-5 apples$. Also it bugs me because of the whole square of a number equaling a negative part of $i$

Comment: But notice you can't have $\sqrt{4 apples}$..... There is no mathatical object that if we multiply it by itself the result is an apple, so $\sqrt{apple}$ is nonsense.  We *can* have $i$ apples, by having one apple putting it in a trust fund facing north, with the stipulation that when a north wind blows, you will owe a person Joe one apple.  Then you have $i$ apples and when you multiply that by $i$ you will have $-1$ apple.

Comment: Thing is there is no *real* number that when squared is $-1$. So you can wrap head as *real* number.  But it must be something else.  But in two dimensional space of vectors where $(m,v) + (n,w) = (m+n, v+w)$ and define $(m,v)\cdot (n,w) = ||(m,v)||\times||(n,w)||$ at the angle of $arg(m,v) + arg(n,w)$ then .... indeed... we *do* get that $(0,1)\cdot (0,1) = (-1, 0)$.  And that *is* what the model of complex numbers.  A vector $(k,0)$ is a real number as it exists only in the real direction. But $(k,w)$ adds a new dimension.

Comment: @fleablood I agree you can't have$\sqrt{4apples}$ but you can have $\sqrt{4}apples$. But to your second response, yes, I'm having trouble thinking of it as a concept because ever since I was 5 and learnt to count I was taught to think in terms of _real_ numbers. Thanks for the clarafication.

Comment: @mrsamy Thanks a lot for the link. I just saw it and helps a lot

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This has nothing to do with complex numbers. By the same argument, $-1=1$, since$$(-1)^2=1^2\implies\sqrt{(-1)^2}=\sqrt{1^2}\implies-1=1.$$The error lies in assuming that $\sqrt{x^2}=x$. Actually, $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$. In the case of complex numbers, it's even worst, since every complex number (other than $0$) has *four* fourth roots. So, the expression $\sqrt[4]z$ doesn't make sense unless and until you decide which fourth root of $z$ you have in mind. Even then, it will often be false that $\sqrt[4]{z^4}=z$.

Comment: Thanks, I figured I must be missing something since I'd tend to assume that people who are more advanced at math than me and say $i$ is a number and the $i=\sqrt{-1}$ are probably correct.

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Comment: first equation should have square on both sides, for better mirroring of OP question. Unfortunately that's a 1 char change so I can't make it.

Comment: @RossPresser Done. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Square roots don't work like that. With the same argument you used, you could have done
$$
(-1)^2=1^2\ \ \ \implies\ \ \ -1=1.
$$
It has nothing to do with complex numbers.

Answer (score 4):

If this may reconcile you with complex numbers, consider this: a complex number is a pair of reals, and we define

- addition as $(a,b)+(c,d):=(a+b,c+d)$,
- multiplication as $(a,b)(c,d):=(ac-bd,ad+bc)$.

Then we accept the "shorthand" conventions $1=(1,0)$ and $i=(0,1)$. It is an easy matter to show that these rules form a consistent arithmetic with the four basic operation, where you can freely use these equivalences.

We also have the consequences

$$i^2=(0,1)(0,1)=(-1,0)=-1$$

and

$$i^4=(-1,0)(-1,0)=(1,0)=1.$$

But that means in no way that $i=1$. It just means that $i$ is *one* of the solutions of the equation

$$z^4=(1,0)=1.$$

All solutions are (see below)

$$(1,0)=1,\\(0,1)=i,\\(-1,0)=-1,\\(0,-1)=-i.$$

Unless you specify a convention, in the complex we don't know which solution $$\sqrt[4]1$$ denotes.

Final remark: in this discussion, we only used real numbers and the special symbol $i$.

---

$$z^4=(x,y)^4=(x^4-6x^2y^2+y^4,4yx^3-4xy^3)=(1,0)$$ requires $$x=0\lor y=0\lor x^2=y^2$$

(by cancelling the imaginary part).

By plugging these in the real part, we get
$$y^4=1\lor x^4=1\lor -4x^4=-4y^4=1.$$

As $x,y$ are real, the only options are

$$(\pm1,0),(0,\pm1).$$

Answer (score 2):

Think of the complex numbers as a pair of real numbers $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$, but with a really useful property: the product $(x, y)\cdot (0,1) = (-y, x)$. Which shows the rotation characteristic of the number i.

Thinking that way is clear that the number $(0,1)$ has the property of $(0,1)^2 = (-1,0)$.

Answer (score 1):

The thing is that if $m= n$ then we can conclude $f(m)  = f(n)$.

But if $f(m) = f(n)$ we can *not* conclude $m = n$ unless $f$ is one to one.

If $f$ is not one to one is perfectly possible to have $m \ne n$ but $f(m) = f(n)$.

A simple example is $f(x) = x^2 - 3x +6 $  If $x=2$ we get $f(2) = 4 - 6 + 6 = 4$.  And if $x=1$ we get $f(1)=1-3 + 6 = 4$.  So $f(1) = f(2) =4$ but $1\ne 2$.

An even *easier* example is $f(x) = x^4$ and $f(-1) = f(1) = f(i) = f(-i)$ will give us $1^4 = 1$ and $(-1)^4 = 1$ and $i^4 = (i^2)^2 =(-1)^2 =1$ and $(-i)^4 = ((-i)^2)^2=((-1)^2i^2)^2 = (1*(-1))^2 = 1$.

the problem is when sloppy teachers give to impressionable students this *INCORRECT* definition:

> THIS IS WRONG:  $\sqrt[k]{m}$ is equal to the $x$ so that $x^k = m$.

The problem is that there are $k$ *different* $x$ that give $x^k = m$ and so that isn't actually a definition of a single value.

Ex.   $\sqrt{16}$ iss the $x$ so that $x^2= 16$.  Well $4^2 = 16$ and $(-4)^2 = 16$.  So which is it?  is $\sqrt{16} = 4$ of is $\sqrt{16} = -4$.

Well, the answer is we define that $\sqrt{m}$ is the *positive* value $x$ so that $x^2 = m$.

But two things come about from this.

One $\sqrt{x^2} \ne x$.  That is just *wrong*.  $\sqrt{x^2} =|x|$ because we don't know that $x$ is positive.

And 2)  $i^2 = 1$ is a property of $i$ but that does not mean $\sqrt{-1} = i$. Because $i$ is neither positive nor negative.

Anyway.....

tl;dr

There are four values, all different of $x$ so that $x^4 = 1$.  They are $1^4 =1; (-1)^4 = 1; (-i)^4=1$

$\sqrt[4]{x^4} \ne x$.  *IF* $x^4$ is a positive real number then $\sqrt[4]{x^4} = |x|$ and indeed $|1| = |-1| = |i| = |-i|$ but $\sqrt[4]{x^4} \ne x$.

And if $x^4$ is *not* a positive real number we don't actually have a definition for $\sqrt[4]{x^4}$.

Comment: Sorry, I don't like this explanation much, because you take for granted that $x^4=1$ has four solutions, when the OP is still at a stage that he knows about the two real solutions $\pm1$. Strictly speaking, $i$ is just surrealistic, unless you introduce the imaginary and complex numbers with some formalism.

Comment: Point taken.  I was trying explain the error in $\sqrt[4]{x^4} = x$ so $i^4 = 1^4 \implies 1=i$.  I was pointing out that $x^4=1$ has more than $1$ solution and not claiming that I was going to prove that it has exactly four in any way.  But I did demonstrate that there are at least four. Point taken that $i^2 = -1$ is something tossed in from no-where but I didn't think that was really the issue of the question.

Comment: My comment was influenced by the first sentence of the OP, but no worries.